# is there something like a pygame.minimize event?

Tags: python, pygame

I know there is a `pygame.quit`, but how would 
you say `pygame.minimize`?

Does anyone know the command 
for this? I've looked all over the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

### Iconify

> iconify the display surface *pygame.display.iconify()*: *return bool*
>
> Request the window for the display surface be **iconified or hidden**. Not
>   all systems and displays support an iconified display. The function
>   will return True if successfull.
>
> When the display is iconified pygame.display.get_active() will return
>   False. The event queue should receive a **ACTIVEEVENT** event when the
>   window has been iconified.

The underlying system of pygame is SDL

so lets look at the code

```c
static PyObject*
iconify (PyObject* self)
{
    int result;

    VIDEO_INIT_CHECK ();
    result = SDL_WM_IconifyWindow (); // the important line
    return PyInt_FromLong (result != 0);
}
```

Looking at the source for `SDL_WM_IconfiyWindow` we can see the following:

> If the application is running in a window managed environment SDL
>   attempts to iconify/minimise it. If SDL_WM_IconifyWindow is
>   successful, the application will receive a SDL_APPACTIVE loss event
>   (see SDL_ActiveEvent).

So check for the `ACTIVEEVENT` which should be pumped to your event queue when the window is iconfied :)

Comment: Note for future adventurers: quick testing on Ubuntu 18.04 indicates that you don't get the `ACTIVEEVENT` when minimising, and `pygame.display.get_active()` returns true even when the window is minimised.

Answer (score 0):

pygame.WINDOWMINIMIZED

it activates only once when your window is minimized

```
import pygame
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    size = width, height = 200, 200
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    minimize = 1

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.WINDOWMINIMIZED:
                minimize += 1
                print(minimize)
    pygame.quit()
```

This code prints out the number of minimizes. Prints only once per minimize.

Answer (score -1):

There is no event for the minimization of a window, but if you want to check if the window is minimized or if the mouse is in the range of the window, you can use `pygame.key.get_focused()` or `pygame.mouse.get_focused()` respectively.

An example code is below so you can play with these functions yourself.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
window=pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if pygame.[key or mouse].get_focused():
        window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    else:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Iconify: it's not supported on all OS's but it's the event they're looking for and the underlying SDL docs even supports this claim.